# Django initial data serialization error

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to provide initial data for a model in Django. but when i try to run `python manage.py loaddata <fixture path>` I get the following error:

```
django.core.serializers.base.DeserializationError: Problem installing 
fixture '/home/location/fixtures/initial_data.json': 
Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 7 column 10 (char 119)
```

My fixtures or initial data is like this:

```
[
{
    "model": "location.zipcode",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
      "zipcode": 79936,
     }
},
{
    "model": "location.zipcode",
    "pk": 2,
    "fields": {
        "zipcode": 90011,
    }
}
]
```

I have `zipcode` as an IntegerField in Zipcode model.
Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Trailing commas are not valid in JSON so remove them.
That would give:

```
[
{
    "model": "location.zipcode",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
      "zipcode": 79936
     }
},
{
    "model": "location.zipcode",
    "pk": 2,
    "fields": {
        "zipcode": 90011
    }
}
]
```

Comment: YEah, it works, I was trying Json as python dicts . Thank you